# Nested structure and simple structure in memory with the same data?

Tags: c

Given the three following structures (in any architecture of 16 bits or above) :

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
  char d;
  int e[10];
} StructA;

typedef struct {
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
  char d;
} StructB;

typedef struct {
  StructB sb;
  int e[10];
} StructC;
```

Then I declare :

```
StructA sa;
StructC sc;
```

**Let's assume the impossible fact that sa and sc point to the same address for comparison purpose**.

What I understood is that sa, sa.a, sc, sc.sb and sc.sb.a would share the same address given the (impossible) above condition.

My question is : Given sa and sc start at the same address, can I take for granted that sa.e and sc.e also start at the same address given a struct is contiguous in memory (but padding) ? Can padding get in the way of my guess ? Would using memcpy on sa into sc be valid ?

Comment: you could put both struct to the union to make them share an address
```union { structA sa; structC sc; } u;```

Answer (score 1):

The C memory model is somewhat high-level and assumes that all objects (variables) in memory have a type, called *effective type*. If you somehow manage to allocate `sa` and `sc` on the same address through some linker tricks, you are doing things beyond the scope of the C language. And so no behavior is guaranteed, it could confuse the compiler and it is undefined behavior.

Had you allocated two structs at the same address by using `union`, it would be another story. In such a case each individual struct will still use padding however, so there's no guarantees unless you know for sure how each struct is padded. If each struct was member of the same union, you could safely memcpy between them using `sizeof` the union, even if one union member is smaller than the other.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you I'll clarify. The point is not to make sa and sc share the same address, I made the assumption for mere address comparison. In real they would of course have a different address and what I want to know is if their memory alignment is, at the end, identical. If you want a more relevant example imagine software 1 sends a struct StructA as, say, a byte array, and software 2 receives it and parse the byte array as StructC. Would that work?

Comment: @Kinxil Well basically there's no guarantees by the language. There may be guarantees by a specific compiler, but writing code relying on such is non-portable. You could use non-standard tricks like #pragma pack to disable padding. In the end, simply refrain from doing very strange things: if you want to "type pun" between two structs then place them in the same union, period.